# Convert the difference between two dates into an integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date-frame (`df`) which the head looks like:

```
        DATE  BBG  FLAG  DATE_DIFF
0 2014-03-04    A     0        NaT
1 2014-04-04    B     1    31 days
2 2014-04-07    C     0     3 days
3 2014-04-08    D     0     1 days
4 2014-04-09    E     0     1 days
```

the column `DATE_DIFF` is the difference between the date in a row and the date in the row above.  I used the following to calculate `DATE_DIFF`:

```
df['DATE_DIFF'] = (df['DATE']-df['DATE'].shift(1))
```

I am looking for a way to convert the DATE_DIFF column to interger so the resulting data-frame would look like:

```
        DATE  BBG  FLAG  DATE_DIFF
0 2014-03-04    A     0        NaN
1 2014-04-04    B     1         31 
2 2014-04-07    C     0          3 
3 2014-04-08    D     0          1 
4 2014-04-09    E     0          1
```

I have tried to use:

```
df['DATE_DIFF'] = (df['DATE']-df['DATE'].shift(1)).astype(int)
```

but that just gives me the error:

```
TypeError: cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [int32]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can do the exact same thing you are currently doing just add `dt.days`

```
df['diff'] = (df['DATE']-df['DATE'].shift(1)).dt.days

    DATE    BBG FLAG    diff
0   2014-03-04  A   0   NaN
1   2014-04-04  B   1   31.0
2   2014-04-07  C   0   3.0
3   2014-04-08  D   0   1.0
4   2014-04-09  E   0   1.0
```

just note that the dtype will be a float not an int because the first row is NaN

Answer (score 0):

If you have two date objects, you can just subtract them.

```
from datetime import date

d0 = date(2008, 8, 18)
d1 = date(2008, 9, 26)
delta = d1 - d0
print delta.days
```

The relevant section of the docs:
https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html